# How can i add data to specific row in TableView?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, fxml

I'm trying to add data to tableview repeatedly. But it doesn't append the data, it just overwrites it. How can i append the data to tableview without deleting old data from the table? Is there any way for me to tell to the program that the row it's trying to write on is not empty?

**UserController Class**

```
package entropy.myproject1;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class UsersController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, Integer> colID;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> colPassword;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<User, String> colUsername;

    @FXML
    private TableView<User> table;

    RegisterController registerController = RegisterController.getInstance();
    ObservableList<User> userList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
        new User(registerController.registeredUser.getId(),registerController.registeredUser.getUsername(),registerController.registeredUser.getPassword())
    );

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        colID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User,Integer>("id"));
        colUsername.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User,String >("username"));
        colPassword.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<User,String>("password"));
        table.setItems(userList);
    }
}
```

**Register Controller Class**

```
package entropy.myproject1;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RegisterController {
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private static final RegisterController instance = new RegisterController();
    public static RegisterController getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }

    @FXML
    private Button buttonAdd;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfID;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfPassword;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfUsername;
    public User registeredUser = User.getInstance();
    @FXML
    void addOnClick(ActionEvent event){
        registeredUser.setId(Integer.parseInt(tfID.getText()));
        registeredUser.setUsername(tfUsername.getText());
        registeredUser.setPassword(tfPassword.getText());
        System.out.println(registeredUser.toString());
    }
    @FXML
    void showListOnClick(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("userspage.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("User List");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**User Class**

```
package entropy.myproject1;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class User {
    private SimpleIntegerProperty id;
    private SimpleStringProperty username;
    private SimpleStringProperty password;
    private static final User instance = new User();

    public User(Integer id, String username, String password) {
        this.id =new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.username =new SimpleStringProperty(username);
        this.password = new SimpleStringProperty(password);
    }

    public User() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username.get();
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password.get();
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = new SimpleStringProperty(username);
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = new SimpleStringProperty(password);
    }
    public static User getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return id+" "+username+" "+password;
    }
}
```

Comment: there's a single user in your data and the addOnClick changes the properties of that single user .. so your code behaves exactly you it should :) Please study the api of ObservableList to learn how to add a new user. And _do not_ use static scope for anything, particularly not for data. Plus: for future questions, please provide a [mcve] (you are near, improve a bit in the the _M_!, nothing unrelated but reproducible :) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I noticed that @kleopatra and working on it :D. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: _working on it_ assuming you mean the [mcve] - good :) Because there seems to be an error on how you use the RegisterController: the fields are annotated as being injected, so it has to be loaded (__not__ instantiated)